# Doctrine, join con condiciones en el ON

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Quiero hacer la siguiente consulta en doctrine

```
SELECT distinct(o.id) 
FROM "order" o 
JOIN sap_order_status s ON (o.state_order_id = s.id OR o.state_order_id is null ) and (s."cancelled" = false)
```

Pero no se como se debería añadir la condición del `OR` dentro del `ON` en `createQuery`

Comment: Has probado hacerla en el where!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario hacer un OR dentro del ON del JOIN. En lugar de esto puedes usar leftJoin, ya que, si no me equivoco, quieres obtener todos los registros de la tabla 'order', aunque no tengan ningún registro de 'sap_order_status' asociado. La consulta de doctrine sería algo así:

```
$repositorio = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Order::class);
$qb = $repositorio->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->leftJoin('o.state_order', 'so')
    ->where('so.cancelled = false');
$resultado = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

No te olvides de:

- Importar la clase '**`Order`**'
- En el leftJoin, el '**`o.state_order`**', debería corresponderse con el nombre de la propiedad de la clase '**`Order`**' que tiene la relación con la clase '**`OrderStatus`**'.

Espero que te sirva, saludos!